# How to make code in a Firefox Extension execute on a timer

Tags: firefox-addon

Today is my first day working with firefox extensions.

Basically I am making an extension that will be used on an internal network to check a web server for new notifications.

I used the wizard on the mozilla page to make a skeleton extension and then mainly edited overlay.js with some ajax code.

I am using the "load" event listener to call a setTimeout to my ajax call which then loops with setTimeouts.

The problem appears to be that the "load" event listener is executed on each new browser window. I just want one global timer for this to work off of.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using
which seems like what i would want. The problem is I can't figure out how to import the jsm file. What is the directory structure?

**Update:**

When trying this:

chrome.manifest

```
content   spt                 chrome/content/
skin      spt   classic/1.0   chrome/skin/
locale    spt   en-US         chrome/locale/en-US/


overlay   chrome://browser/content/browser.xul   chrome://spt/content/ff-overlay.xul
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://spt/skin/overlay.css


resource mycontent chrome/content/
```

First 5 lines of chrome/content/overlay.js

```
try{
    Components.utils.import("resource://spt/mycontent/ajax.jsm");
}catch(err){
    alert(err);
}
```

I get this error:

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://spt/content/overlay.js ::  :: line 2" data: no]

Or when if I remove the resource alias from chrome.manifest and use this at the beginning of overlay.js

```
try{
    Components.utils.import("chrome://spt/content/ajax.jsm");
}catch(err){
    alert(err);
}
```

I get this error:

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://spt/content/overlay.js ::  :: line 3" data: no]

Comment: I updated the page you found in an attempt to make the answer to your question about registering the code module easier to find. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes that is much clearer but I still can't get it to work. On trying to do the import I get the error: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://spt/content/overlay.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 3"  data: no]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you have code that should be shared between windows (and should not be executed when a new window is loaded) and that don't need access to the chrome, use [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules).

You can import your modules with:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://youraddon/your_module.jsm");
```

provided that you setup `resource` in your [`chrome.manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome_registration). E.g. if you add

```
resource youraddon modules/
```

then you the file must be stored in `/path/to/your/addon/modules/your_module.jsm`.

**Further notes:**

- Code modules don't have to have the file extensions `.jsm`. You can leave it `.js`. Works better sometimes with certain editors (and syntax highlighting etc).
- Afaik you cannot use `setTimeout` in a module as it has no access to the `window` object. I suggest to use [`nsITimer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/nsITimer).

Comment: I am getting an error with this method as well. [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://spt/content/overlay.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2"  data: no]

Comment: @Mike: Please post the relevant code. Otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: @Mike: If you have `resource mycontent chrome/content/` then the URI would be `resource://mycontent/ajax.jsm`. You cannot use `chrome:` URIs before Firefox 4.

Comment: @Mike: Is the file located under `chrome/content/`?

Comment: Yeah it is right there next to overlay.js, chrome/content/ajax.jsm

Comment: @Mike: Mmh. That is strange. It should work then. Double check everything.

Comment: Alright, so now I started from complete scratch. I created the addon with mozilla's addon creator. I copied ajax.jsm into chrome/content ,added that single line to chrome.manifest and I added my try/catch block to overlay.js  I get a file not found error still.

Comment: Apparently it is an error with ajax.jsm, i just deleted most of the code and it now imports correctly. I will report back when I get more details.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah that it is a problem. Sometimes I'm also wondering why something does not work and I don't get a decent error message. And in the end it is a problem in a module... that is really annoying.

Comment: I had an alert function in the ajax file. Also I can't actually have the XMLHttpRequest in there either. I imagine due to the reason you stated above about the window object. So I imagine the best way to handle this is to have all my code in the overlay.js and use the code module just to store a boolean that determines whether it is already running.

Comment: @Mike: On way or the other. You can also create connections to other servers via XPCOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections

Comment: This code module doesn't seem to be working globaly anyway. When I open a new firefox window, the variable gets reset.

Comment: @Mike: Are you modifying the variable outside of the module? Code inside modules is not executed twice, that is for sure. The documentation says: *Note: Each scope which imports a module receives a by-value copy of the exported symbols in that module. Changes to the symbol's value will not propagate to other scopes (though an object's properties will be manipulated by reference).* So if you do from the outside `module.status = false`, then this would not be propagated to other code. You have to export and *object* and change its property.

Comment: Oh, I see... Would I be able to use a setter function in the module to do this then or is it not possible to do what I want in this way?

Comment: @Mike: Not 100% sure what you mean, but you can export a function `setSomething` that takes a value and stores it in a variable private to the module. You can also export a function `getSomething` that returns that value. This works. Did you mean that?

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I meant(sorry it wasn't too clear), i will give it a try.

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks for all the help.